# Nodejs Date() "Hours" different from getHours()

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Does anyone know why the "hh" returned by dateTime is different from the "hh" returned by time in the below?

```js
//Create new Date() Object
var dateTime = new Date();
console.log(dateTime);

//Extract Date
var date = dateTime.getDate() + "/" + (parseInt(dateTime.getMonth())+1) + "/" + dateTime.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
console.log(date);

//Extract Time
var time = (dateTime.getHours()) + ":" + (parseInt(dateTime.getMinutes())+1) + ":" + (parseInt(dateTime.getSeconds())+1);
console.log(time);
```

Comment: `parseInt(dateTime.getMinutes())+1` why add one? something like `11:00` is a valid hour, while `11:60` isn't. Same with seconds. Also, no need to parse these - they are already numbers.

Comment: Logging `dateTime` gives you utc time (that's what the `z` at the end is telling you). Calling `getHours()` give you hours in *local* time.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice, you're 100% correct, adding the 1 is not valid and also parseInt is not necessary... Looks much better having removed it now!

Comment: 2019-11-21T08:26:54.781Z
21/11/19
10:26:54

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks so much, that explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Much better, thanks so much for the advice!

```
//Create new Date() Object
var dateTime = new Date();
console.log(dateTime);
//Extract Date
var date = dateTime.getDate() + "/" + (parseInt(dateTime.getMonth())+1) + "/" + dateTime.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
console.log(date);

//Extract Time
var time = (dateTime.getHours()) + ":" + dateTime.getMinutes() + ":" + dateTime.getSeconds();
console.log(time);
```

**Output:**
2019-11-21T08:26:54.781Z
21/11/19
10:26:54